# I'm using i18n in nuxt.js. Change an object through a v-if statement

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

If changed locale to English, /en will be attached to the router.

So I used a conditional statement using a router.

```
// english
v-row(v-if="$route.path.includes('/en')")
    
// korean(default)
v-row(v-else)
```

The problem is...

i18n detects the language of the browser(if english) and shows English page to the user.

In this case, even though it is an English page, the condition I wrote does not apply because /en is not attached to the router.

Is there a way to set the condition in the language currently being shown, not the router condition?

Comment: Why don't you access the value of the locale itself directly? Try something like `$i18n.locale`. Also, if it's not working please provide a quick [repro].

Comment: May you please elaborate on how and what helped you here?